# Workaround for filtering nested Geojson in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: json, filter, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

i have a question about filter expression

my scheme looks like

```json
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {
        "a": "a",
        "b": {
          "c": "c",
          "d": "d"
        },
        "f #1": {
          "g": "g"
        },
        "f #2": {
          "h": "h"
        }
      }
```

and i wonder is there any possibilities to get that deep?

like `map.setFilter( 'my_layer', ['==', ['get', ['b']['d']], 'd'] )`

if no, how can i workaround this limitation? i need arrays here

Comment: flat all dicts and add common id for all 